# Modify Table of Content and Summary geometry

Tags: geometry

I am currently writing a report, quite a long one actualy. However I have a limit on the number of pages I can write. I have a grand total of 21 pages **including** the summary, the table of contents (**TOC**) and the table of figures (**TOF**).

Somehow my summary is too long (lots of sections) and spans accros two pages. However when I compile, it seems like there is a big margin at the top of the page :

[image: top of the page]

I would like to know if I can change the geometry just for these pages in order to display them on one page only !

Thanks :)

Comment: In report class, `\tableofcontents` etc. use `\chapter*{\contentsname}`.  Easiest is to modify `\@makeschapterhead` to remove the 50pt gap, or use a package like titlesec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I used that works :

```tex
\newgeometry{top = 0.1in, bottom = 0.1in, left = 1in, right = 1in}
 % ---- sumary & TOC

\newpage
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: If this reply is part of your question, please move it there, using the Edit button. Here we like to establish 1 problem = 1 question, and each answer shall be one exact solution.

Comment: This is not, it is the actual solution i used

Comment: Then edit this post, stating clearly that it is an answer.